# Powershell Script to install VLC stops working if I add a quiet argument

Tags: powershell, deployment, windows-installer, vlc

I have the following script that takes the msi installer in the same directory as my script, installs it with the mst also in the same directory:

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -WorkingDirectory $dir -ArgumentList '/i "vlc-3.0.4-win64.msi" /t "vlc-3.0.4-win64.mst"'
```

This seems to work fine (I have to next through the installer but it seems to pick up the transforms just fine) however if I try and add in a /qn to the arguments in -ArgumentList (which should be the argument for quiet install with no UI from what I understand) the script runs but doesn't seem to install the program at all.

I'm sure I'm being stupid here but I'm not sure where.

Edit, looking at the log file I get:

```
MSI (s) (B4:14) [13:02:41:978]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (B4:14) [13:02:41:978]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1708 
MSI (s) (B4:14) [13:02:41:978]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (B4:14) [13:02:41:978]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (B4:14) [13:02:41:978]: Product: VLC media player 3.0.4 (64-bit) -- Installation failed.
```

Comment: Add `/l*v C:\path\to\install.log`, re-run, then inspect `install.log`.

Comment: Error 1708 means "installation operation failed". What does the log say before that?

Comment: Could be a problem with the package itself. Instead of `/qn` try `/quiet`. What happens then?

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out and I was, in the end, being (very) stupid. PoeweShell ISE wasn't loaded elevated so when I was running the script to test it with the quiet argument it was running it fine but not able to complete as it can't ask me to elevate it on a silent install. Running it from the ISE elevated fixes the issue. Thanks all!

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into a question. Feel free to post your solution as an answer of your own (don't forget to accept it).

Comment: Ahh, apologies @Ansgar I'll do that (Sorry, I'm new here)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've figured it out and I was, in the end, being (very) stupid. PowerShell ISE wasn't loaded elevated so when I was running the script to test it with the quiet argument it was running it fine, but not able to complete as it can't ask me to elevate it on a silent install. Running it from the ISE elevated fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For remote vlc installation via powershell, you need to open a session on the remote machine before running the .msi installer. For example:

```
$computer = "172.16.83.8"
$file1 = '\\WIN-LAB-SERVER\Servidor\vlc.msi'
Copy-Item -Path $file1 -Destination "\\$computer\tmp\vlc.msi"
$s1 = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer
Invoke-Command -session $s1 -scriptblock {
    msiexec.exe /i c:\tmp\vlc.msi /qn /L*V c:\tmp\vlc.log
}
```